# java Object casting

Tags: java, object, casting, javabeans

public void test(Object obj){

```
       //Here i have to set the values of the obj using its setter . 
    }
```

Test can be invoked with two objects as parameter. EG: test(standalone) and test(webapp), where standalone and webapp are beans.

```
public class standalone{
      int version;
   //setter and getter
}

public class Webapp{
     String version;
   //setter and getter
}
```

This test method has to set the values accordin to the parameter object.
Eg: IF i pass standalone as param. standalone's setter method shd be called. How to achieve this?

Note : Without using interface. How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: you can do it using inheritance and polymorphism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void setVersion(Object obj, int v) throws Exception {
  for (Method m : obj.getClass().getMethods()) {
    final Class<?>[] t = m.getParameterTypes();
    if (m.getName().equals("setVersion") && t.length == 1)
      m.invoke(obj, t[0] == String.class? String.valueOf(v) : v);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks.. If i want to invoke the setversion but the set versions are of different type. How i hav to invoke that?

Comment: Yes it is the ans i'm looking for.. :)

Comment: But How to call it dynamically, if it accept differrent type of param?

Answer (score 0):

In the simpliest way you could do like this:

```
public void test(Object obj) {

    if( obj instanceof Standalone ) {
        ((Standalone)obj).setVersion(1);
    } else if (obj instanceof WebApp ) {
        ((WebApp)obj).setVersion(1);
    }

}
```

Try to avoid use of reflection to achieve this because it will make refactoring tasks really hard. The same would be applied to compare the class name with a string.

**If you want something more elegant you could do something like this:**

```
public class abstract AbstractEnv {
    int version = 0;
    // setters and getters
}

public class Standalone extends AbstractEnv{
}

public class Webapp extends AbstractEnv{
}
```

with this approach you can configure it like this:

```
public void test(AbstractEnv obj) {

    obj.setVersion(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your classes should implement an interface like `VersionSettable`. Which declares the method `setVersion(int version)`.

```
public class standalone implements VersionSettable {
      int version;
   //setter and getter
}

public class Webapp implements VersionSettable {
      int version;
   //setter and getter
}

interface VersionSettable {
    setVersion(int version);
}
```

Then you can change your test method to this:

```
public void test(VersionSettable obj){
   obj.setVersion(17);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make both StandAlone and WebApp implement an interface, eg

```
interface VersionSettable {
    void setVersion(int version);
}

public class Standalone implements VersionSettable{
      int version;
   //setter and getter
}

public class Webapp implements VersionSettable{
      int version;
   //setter and getter
}

public void test(VersionSettable versionSettable){
   versionSettable.setVersion(42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think would be best if you use inheritance in this case, because (as far as I can get it)
both Standalone and WebApp are Applications.

So you can define a top class "Application" and both StandaloneApp and WebApp extend it, because an **"is a" relationship** could be defined.

Skeleton code:

```
define class Application
define class StandaloneApp extends Application, implements method setVersion(int)
define class WebApp extends Application, implements method setVersion(int)

define test method, which accepts "Application" obj in the arguments
```

Also you can apply any of the interface solutions, presented above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
interface SetVersion{
    void setVersion(int version);
}
class Standalone implements SetVersion{}
class WebApp implements SetVersion{}
public void test(SetVersion version){
      version.setVersion(1);
    }
```

Or the simplest way would be to use `.instanceOf`

```
if(obj.instanceOf(Standalone)){

}
```